# Using ogr2ogr on Anaconda

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, json, anaconda

I am building a Choropleth map in D3.JS.

In order to do that, I have downloaded a map from Eurostat.

From the GeoJSON file, I want to extract the country for the visualization, in my case Portugal.

As I am planning to use OGR2OGR, I have installed the GDAL package on Anaconda and in order to extract the map of Portugal, I am using the following code:

```
ogr2ogr -where FID='PT' pt.geojson CNTR_RG_01M_2016_3857.json
```

But it is triggering an error.

> org2org -where FID="PT" pt.geojson CNTR_RG_01M_2016_3857.json
>    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

How do I use org2org on Anaconda?

Comment: `-where` (and `-sql`) need SQL expressions as *strings*; enclose the filter expression with `"`.

Comment: Just realized that @PolyGeo edited the question. I am following this tutorial (http://datawanderings.com/2018/08/19/extracting-countries-from-geojson-with-ogr2ogr/), but for the Python I am using Anaconda

Comment: You're trying to run a command line tool in python, quit python and run `ogr2ogr` from the command prompt,

Comment: Running in the cmd gives the following error: 'ogr2ogr' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Make sure you're using the Anaconda cmd prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run `ogr2ogr -where FID='PT' pt.geojson CNTR_RG_01M_2016_3857.json` I had to use Anaconda Prompt.

One just needs to make sure that the datasource, in my case the file *CNTR_RG_01M_2016_3857.json*,  is in the same folder as the environment. It may not be possible to work on the base (root) environment, so I would advise to create an environment before.